# There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first - WCF

Tags: sql-server, web-services, wcf, exception, sqldatareader

I have functions that is being called within a WCF service function and I get the exception stated above at the subcategoriesGenerator function on the excute reader line 
isn't it supposed for the cmd created in the second function to a completely different instance than the other one
please I'm confused and I need help ant suggestions?

```
public static List<Category> categoryGenerator(ref SqlConnection con)
    {
        Category category = null;
        List<Category> list = null;
        List<SubCategory> subcategoryList = null;
        string categoryName = null;
        string categoryLink = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_categoriesgenerator", con);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

        while(reader.Read())
        {
            categoryName = reader["CategoryName"].ToString();
            categoryLink = reader["CategorySEO"].ToString() + "/";
            subcategoryList = subcategoriesGenerator(ref con, Convert.ToInt32(reader["CategoryId"].ToString()));

            category.categoryName = categoryName;
            category.categoryLink = categoryLink;
            category.subcategories = subcategoryList;

            list.Add(category);

            category = null;
        }
        reader.Close();
        return list;
    }//end CategoryGenerator

  public static List<SubCategory> subcategoriesGenerator(ref SqlConnection con, int categoryId)
    {
        SubCategory subcategory = null;
        List<SubCategory> list = null;
        string SubCategoryName = null;
        string SubCategoryLink = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_subcategoriesgenerator", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categoryID", categoryId);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while(reader.Read())
        {
            SubCategoryName = reader["SubcategoryName"].ToString();
            SubCategoryLink = reader["CategorySEO"].ToString() + "/" + reader["SubcategorySEO"] + "/";
            subcategory.subcategoryName = SubCategoryName;
            subcategory.subcategoryLink = SubCategoryLink;
            list.Add(subcategory);
            subcategory = null;
        }
        reader.Close();

        return list;
    }// end subcategoriesGenerator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't open another reader in your connection while you have an open reader. You have to extract the call of the function "subcategoriesGenerator" outside of your first while-statement or create a second database-connection. I prefer this solution:

First, collect all categories
Second, loop over all categories and query the subcategories and append them to your category-object